# Original error: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.UiAutomator2Exception

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium

- Getting unknown server-side error while running the script.
- The script would terminate while scrolling else it would work fine.

**Log error:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.UiAutomator2Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomation not connected!
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.utils.UiExpressionParser.invokeMethod(UiExpressionParser.java:251)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.utils.UiScrollableParser.consumeMethodCall(UiScrollableParser.java:124)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.utils.UiScrollableParser.parse(UiScrollableParser.java:60)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.utils.UiAutomatorParser.consumeStatement(UiAutomatorParser.java:93)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.utils.UiAutomatorParser.parse(UiAutomatorParser.java:49)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.utils.LocationHelpers.toSelectors(LocationHelpers.java:95)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.utils.LocationHelpers.toSelector(LocationHelpers.java:88)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.findElement(FindElement.java:144)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.safeHandle(FindElement.java:75)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:37)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:250)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:241)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
```

*** **Element info:**

```
{Using=-android uiautomator, value=new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(" val "));}
```

**Appium Log:**

Answer (score 0):

restarting `adb` before the test run with `adb kill-server; adb start-server`. 
because sometimes the `appium` server having issue with adb so by restarting you can avoid this problem not every time when this error comes you can again start executing if not solved then please restart `adb` and then start executing script that will work..
Happy to help...
In case you have any doubts comment down below..

Comment: - I did the same but in between of scrolling on the screen, the script would fail.

Comment: unable to get it why is it so

Comment: Yes getting the same error. I tried thrice by adb commands but that thing can't help me.

Comment: Solved the issue by uninstalling:                                                                         
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test                           
abd unistall io.appium.unlock                                                                         
adb uninstall io.appium.settings

Answer (score 0):

I was in an Android app, and when I opened a web page, I guess appium was monitoring the app, but couldn't monitor another thread that opened the web page in the browser (although that's what it looks like on the phone), or could it be something like a browser page jump? I don't know exactly why, but I was able to get the display layer elements by restarting webdriver. The python code is as follows:

```py
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, self.capabilities)
self.driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value='//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc="more"]').click()
# restart webdriver
self.driver.quit()
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, self.capabilities)
#
self.driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value='//android.widget.TextView[@text="link"]').click()
```